# Ansible to check for unused disks of certain size and create a volume group

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am pretty new to Ansible and a brand new member of Stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a playbook that would look for unused disks (can be SAN, Solidfire, or localdisk). Filter them according to the size variable and create a volume group out of those disks that fall within the criteria.

For example the server has 2x 50GB disk and 2x 100GB disk.

I want it so that even if user enters `51Gb` size or `49 GB` size, the playbook should be able to take into account the +-5gb error margin.

The part where I am stuck is how to filter unused disks by size with the +- 5gb error margin.

I can look up the unused disks by

```
set fact:
  disks: "{{ansible_local.unused_disks}}"
```

this gives a list of unused disks. But how can I filter that list for specic size with error margin descried above ?

**EDIT**

Yup you are right. `ansible_local.unused_disks` does not exists.

On the server I checked before it was put there using custom facts. Which will not be the case on every single server. Hence I will need to find another way to look up the disks.

I checked with another SA and was given this code.

```
 - name: Discover Disks
   set_fact:
     disks: "['/dev/{{item.key}}']"
   when:
     - not item.value.partitions
     - not item.value.holder
     - not item.value.links.ids
     - item.key | search ("sd")
   with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}"
```

But it is giving me an output that only shows the first unused device found instead of all unused device in a list. So I will need help with this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ansible_local is not a usual ansible feature. I googled it. Is it vagrant stuff?

anyway, thing you want to do, is to process a list, skipping some of its elements. It's easy to do.

```
- name: do something with a disks of a proper size
  command: echo do somewhing with {{ item }}
  with_items:' {{ ansible_local.unused_disks }}'
  when: min_value <= ansible_devices[item].sectors * ansible_devices[item].sectorsize <= max_value 
  vars:
    min_value: '{{ user_input * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1.05 }}'
    max_value: '{{ user_input * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1.05 }}'
```

Comment: Yup you are right. ansible_local.unused_disks does not exists. On the server I checked before it was put there using custom facts. Which will not be the case on every single server. Hence I will need to find another way to look up the disks. I checked with another SA and was given this code.
` - name: Discover Disks
     set_fact:
       disks: "['/dev/{{item.key}}']"
     when:
       - not item.value.partitions
       - not item.value.holder
       - not item.value.links.ids
       - item.key | search ("sd")
    with_dict: "{{ ansible_devices }}" `

Comment: I have tried multiple times I am not sure why my code shows up in one line when I actually wrote with proper syntax. I will have to figure that part out.